# FactoryGirl set attribute with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I have a `Note` object attached to a `Course`, I want to randomly set the `@note.number` to `rand(@note.course.sections)` in FactoryGirl. I tried:

```
  factory :note do
    association :course
    number { ranb(course.sections) }
    content { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(paragraph_count = 1).join(" ") }
  end
```

It doesn't work and says the course is nil. What's the right way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the relationship between `Course#sections` and `Note#number`, also I can only assume you've defined the `Course` factory. I've tested the following, and it works fine:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    sequence(:sections)
  end

  factory :note do
    course
    number { rand(course.sections) }
  end
end


note = FactoryGirl.create(:note)
# => <Note id: 11, course_id: 12, number: 6, ...>
note.course
# => <Course id: 12, sections: 9, ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have tested it in console too. The error was actually emitted by `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:note)`, since I didn't pass in `course:`.